# My Online store generates a segmentation fault and i cant figure out why

Tags: c++, oop, segmentation-fault

I am working on a homework assignment for an advanced C++ course. The program simulates the back-end of an online store. Luckily there is an autograder for the assignment and my Product and Customer classes pass every test case, however my Store class has a segmentation fault somewhere, and since the auto-grader unit-tests each function, I know the fault is occuring in addProduct(), it may also be occurring in getProduct() since addProdcut() calls getProduct().

I am not sure where the fault is occurring, I've tried to recreate it on my machine using driver code, but the auto grader just says that a segmentation fault occurred and doesn't tell me where. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIwXS.jpg

```
//numProducts is a static int and a data member of the Store class
static int Store::numProducts = 0;
//The products array is an array of Product pointers maximum size 100
Product* products[100];

//Each product has a unique id of type integer

bool Store::addProduct(int productID, const char productName[])
{
    Product* product = getProduct(productID);
    if (numProducts == 99) { return false; }
    else if (product != nullptr) { return false; }
    else
    {
        Product* newProduct = new Product(productID, productName);
        products[numProducts] = newProduct;
        numProducts++;
        return true;
    }
}

Product* Store::getProduct(int productID)
{
    for (Product* product : products)
    {
        if (product->getID() == productID) {return product;}
    }
    return nullptr;
}

int Product::getID() const { return id; }

//here is the Product constructor, however i know that this is perfectly fine since the product class passes all unit-testing.

Product::Product(int productID, const char productName[]) :
    id(productID), inventory(0), numSold(0), totalPaid(0.0) {
        setName(productName);
        strcpy_s(this->description, "");
    }
//And here is the setName function in case you want to recreate this
void Product::setName(const char productName[]) {
    if (strlen(productName) > 0) {
        strcpy_s(this->name, productName);
    }
    else {
        //Counter is a static int
        counter++;
        ostringstream oss;
        oss << "Product " << counter;
        strcpy_s(this->name, oss.str().c_str());
    }        
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: I'm not sure where the fault is occurring, i don't know how to provide a verifiable example, I was hoping that someone more advanced than me would be able to see the code and spot how a segmentation fault may occur.

Comment: Did you read  the link provided? [mcve] is **required** for any, and all "why doesn't my code work?" kind of questions. Writing an answer without one, more often, than not, will involve guessing, which we would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to zero-check *product* (compare it with *nullptr*) before calling its method

```
    product->getID();
```

in

```
    Store::getProduct()
```

Obviously, calling a method by a zero-initialized pointer isn't a good idea.

Comment: Yes, calling a method on an uninitialized pointer is not a good idea, but if a pointer is uninitialized - comparing it with `nullptr` won't help. But, since it seems, that `products` are a global variable - it _is_ zero-initialized.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem, i just needed to make sure i wasnt calling getID on a nullptr, appreciate it!